# Move folder outside doc root

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to move my (wordpress) wp-contents directory outside wordpress site root folder.

```
WP path: /home/me/domains/my_domain/public_html/
Target wp-contents directory: /home/me/domains/stuff/
```

I'm experimenting with htaccess without success...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content(/*)
RewriteRule ^wp-content/(.*)$ /../../stuff/wp-content/$1 [L]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible within `.htaccess` - you'll need to define the Rewrite condition directly in the server's configuration in order to be able to specify directories outside the web root.

The easiest workaround, if you can create them, is using a symbolic link instead. If you do, you may need to add

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

to your .htaccess or Apache configuration.

Comment: I mean site root folder :) Still in /home/me/domains/

Comment: @Psycho I understand. What I say still applies. It's a limitation on Apache's end, not the operating system's, even if all user rights are okay